# Deleting lines in shell script

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

If pattern matches in file i want to delete that line, and also 7 lines following that line.

I know deleting a line if any pattern matches

```
:g/profile/d
```

Above command will delete that line having pattern 'profile'
but how to delete 7 lines afterwards that pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern/,+7d' file
```

This deletes the line containing `pattern` and the following 7 lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -v n=7 '/profile/{p=n-1} --p>0{next} 1' file
```